# Перехват нажатий клавиш Назад и Домой

Tags: android, java

Есть код, перехватывает нажатие кнопки назад, нужно чтобы перехватывал так же кнопку домой, примерно так:

```
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK or KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME)) {
        return true;
    } 
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: не нужно перехватывать кнопку home. Но если очень сильно хочется, что бы пользователи проклинали, зарегистрируйте Ваше приложение как launcher.

Comment: Ну да, верно, переборщил что-то с перехватом сворачивания.